# SDK Manager not opening

Tags: android

My SDK manager is not opening (working on Windows 8), it's showing :

> [SDK Manager] 'C:\Users\pinki\Desktop\ANDROI~1\ANDROI~1\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe -s'                is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

I've looked for android.bat file in sdk\tools it's not there. Where will I find it?
or some other problem is there?

Comment: If you are opening it in eclipse, then provide correct path in `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `SDK location bar` - put your `C:\Path\to\Android\android-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

One way to manually open your SDK Manager is to go to the folder where you've saved all the Android packages and go to `C:/{Your Path}/Android/tools/` and in that folder you will find `android.bat`.

As for solving this for the long term, check to make sure you have your environment variables properly set or if you're running in Eclipse, make sure you set the proper SDK location by navigating `Window->Preferences->Android`.  If the SDK Location entered at the top does not match the actual location, be sure to fix that to the proper path.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

Open up /tools/android.bat in your favorite text editor

Search for this block of code:

```
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

Replace it with this line:

```
set java_exe="<Path of your JDK>\bin\java.exe"
```

java_exe will be the static of your Java exe.

Run android.bat

Comment: It says I don't have permission to save it there.

Answer (score 0):

Put this string into **PATH** (System variables)

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

Looks like that:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np4lr.png)

p.s. And of course you should have **"java/bin"** folder in your PATH too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the place your SDK is actually located and follow the steps below to update your SDK location?

In Android Studio, go to File -> Project Structure

After the above steps, under Platform Settings -> SDKs, check the home paths of your Java SDK and the Android SDK's you are using in your projects. Make sure they are pointing to the correct places and if not, redirect them by selecting the ... button.

If you are unable to find the SDK, you can download it [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) at the bottom of the page where it says SDK Tools Only.

If you are unable to find the JDK, you can download it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).